# Laravel Bootstrap-Form update route error

Tags: forms, laravel, routes

I have a strange issue cause it appeared without changing anything as I remember.

I have done my form like this ( which was working great )

```
    @extends('admin')

@section('content')

{{ BootForm::open(['model'=>$post,'update'=>'posts.update','files'=>'true']) }}

    {{ BootForm::text('name','Nom') }}

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::textarea('content',$post->content,['class'=>'editor','id'=>'editor']) }}
        @if($errors->first('content'))
           <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $errors->first('content') }}</div>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="img"/>
        @if($errors->first('img'))
            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $errors->first('img') }}</div>
        @endif
    </div>

    <p>{{ BootForm::submit('Modifier') }}</p>

{{ Bootform::close() }}

@stop
```

And my route file :

```
Route::resource('posts','PostsController');
```

But when I submit my form it goes on : 
http://local.dev/posts/4 instead of http://local.dev/myfoldername/public/posts/4

All my others routes are working great ( I have others models )

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that Laravel is built to be used with virtual host that links on public directory and BootForm may have been coded in the same way.

Try to make a virtual host directly on the public directory so you can access the page with something like

`http://something.dev`instead of `http://local.dev/directory/public`

Answer (score -1):

```
{{ BootForm::open(['model'=>$post,'update'=>'posts.update','files'=>'true']) }}
```

where is `$post->id`     you must gone "id" controller

Comment: What do you men by `You must gone`?

Comment: $post->id  You have sent the file controller   
BootForm::open(['model'=>$post,'update'=>'posts.update,$post->id','files'=>'true']) }}

Comment: BootForm already uses the model past in $post to find the correct id, the problem does not come from this line.